# How to test for PackageInstaller.STATUS_FAILURE_INCOMPATIBLE

Tags: android, android-source, packageinstaller

I have an android device and I have changed some strings in the framework and I want to test PackageInstaller statuscodes on it to check if it's actually done. How can I manually trigger each status code of PackageInstaller?

I tried to manually install really old apps but all of them simply got installed without getting blocked by the packageinstaller.